# AppleMusic Api Search Similar Artists

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

I can't find out how to create a search request by the Apple Music Api to get a similar artists. For example, I have the Artist Aerosmith and want to search similar artists with the same genres. 
I'm looking here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi

I can get relationships between a song and albums, an album and an artist. 
I want something like this:

https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/ru/search?offset=0&term=(genres=rock)&limit=10&types=artists

Maybe someone can help me with the term param for it.

Comment: Did you ever find a way arount this? Seems the Apple Music Api sucks :(

Comment: @andres.cianio nope :-(

Comment: Did someone found anything new about this "issue"?

Comment: @user3143691 nope :-(

Comment: Music.fm has a artist.getsimilar method on their API